# Slowest shutter speed possible using a monopod?

Tags: shutter-speed, image-stabilization, monopod

What would be the slowest shutter speed possible while using a monopod and would it make more sense having IS turned on while using a monopod for slow shutter speed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much benefit can one expect from a monopod?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/how-much-benefit-can-one-expect-from-a-monopod)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing. Unlike a tripod, a monopod only improves stability. How much will depend on the particular monopod, its height, the wind, the focal-length you use, how you breath, etc.

What you can hope is that it will improve compared to how you hand-hold. Remember than these is no absolute their either. A common rule of thumb is 1 over the focal-length but recently many photographers claim 1 over twice the focal-length or more. That is because increased resolution requires more stability.

With good breathing, a solid stance, a short focal-length and stabilization on, it is possible to hold 1/4s or a little less but I am not sure at all how this can help you.

In regards to stabilization, yes use the stabilizer as there is still movement to stabilize with a monopod.

Comment: And the most common use for a monopod is to take the weight of very long lenses so that you can get up to the 1/f or 1/2f level in the first place -- not easy with, say, a 12-pound (5.3kg) 400mm/2.8 handheld at all.